# Custom key popup of softkeyboard

Tags: popup, customization, android-softkeyboard

> I am working on soft keyboard.
>
> Now I am working on key popup when any key pressed. For that I added
>   in xml file like,

```
<Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"  android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupview"
     android:popupCharacters="w"/>
```

**popupview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/previewbackground"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="32sp" />
```

**previewbackground.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#bbFFFFFF" /> 
    <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
</shape>
```

> So after adding above configuration in my application, popup looks
>   like shown below,

[image]

> **As we can see popup is shown.But the problem is,**
>
> **1) Pop up shown only when I long press on key.which must be shown on single tap.**
>
> **2) Pop up is showing with cancel button.**
>
> **3) Pop up is not dismissing automatically, I have to press cancel(cross) button, to  manually close pop up.**
>
> Primarily default key popup is like shown in below image,

[image]

> Pop up is showing successfully but I need some customization in popup
>   but I can't find any help to customize pop up.
>
> That's why I tried with this configuration.But the problem is it's not
>   working well as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about popups which contain additional characters or the key preview (a popup that shows a magnified version of the depressed key)?

The android:popupKeyboard and android:popupCharacters are used for additional characters, for example

```
<Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupview"
     android:popupCharacters="2\@"/>
```

this will allow you to long press the 'w' key for accessing characters such as the number 2 and the @ character. The backslash is for escaping special characters.

The key preview is set by setPreviewEnabled(boolean previewEnabled) in the Keyboard view class. It can be either true or false, but i don't know if you can customize it. Look around in the androidIME source https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `keyIcon` i.e drawable as shown below

```
<Key
  android:codes="51"
  android:keyLabel="3"
  android:keyIcon="@drawable/happy_icon"/>
```

And if you need to select long press pop up,
change that xml `popupview` layout `TextView` to `Keyboard` like this

`popupview.xml`

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:keyWidth="10%p"
  android:horizontalGap="0px"
  android:verticalGap="0px"
  android:keyHeight="40dp">
</Keyboard>
```